# Does this sperm remain and contaminate and count as eating sperm

Tags: taharah, waswasa

I’ve been having lots of problems with this issue. When I ejaculate and after sometimes sperm gets on hands after washing hands if i touch anything for 2 days does what I touch get contaminated. Also if I touch my private part for the next two days does sperm go on hand. Also if I touch these objects and then eat does this count as eating sperm. After washing my hands, my hands feel sticky and rough although I can not visually see any sperm. Please someone help.

Comment: Wash your hands thoroughly then?

Comment: I wash my hands for around 20 seconds with hand wash but stiil.